# reference used for template parameter

Tags: c++

I got following code running

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

template<typename a> struct function 
{ 
    void self1(){ cout << "hello world 1111" << endl; }
};

template<typename a> struct function<a&> 
{ 
    void self2() { cout << "hello world 2222" << endl; }
};


int main()
{
    function<int> a;
    a.self1();
    function<int&> b;
    b.self2();
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
hellow world 1111
heloow world 2222
```

Would like to ask the relation ship between the first "struct function" and the second "struct function"

Is the second one classfied as "template specialization" for the first one? (seems not)

I can see that the 2nd one is based on the 1st one. (By removing the 1st one, it is not compilable). But

```
b.self1() is not defined.
```

So somehow the 2nd have redefined the struct to a new one?

Comment: Yes, that's template specialization.

Comment: @GillBates Thx, my usual understanding is that template specialization would define the type to bool/int and so on. Now it is defined to be a reference. I will look more into the knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can see that the 2nd one is based on the 1st one. (By removing the
>   1st one, it is not compilable). But
>
> b.self1() is not defined. So somehow the 2nd have redefined the struct
>   to a new one?

`function` is a struct template, it's not a struct by itself. At the moment of instantiating one like you did : `function<int> a;` the compiler generates a `struct function_int` that contains `int` for all `T's` (or `a's` in this case).

```
template<typename a> struct function<a&>
```

This is a specialisation of the struct template that's used for when `a` is a reference type. This specialisation can't use any members/methods of the "original" struct template.

Comment: What does it mean that the specialization shares nothing with the primary template? It's a specialization, it wouldn't compile if the primary template didn't exist. Isn't it enough?

Comment: @Skypjack In that you can't use `self1()` in that specialization.

Comment: I see your point. Well, actually _share nothing_ is not the best way to say that. My two cents. :-)

Comment: @skypjack Updated answer, _anything_ was a bit explicit indeed.